# Evitar tracking de sesion en Java

Tags: java, sql, netbeans, servlets, session

¿Como puedo evitar el tracking de sesion?. Ya que tengo una aplicacion cada vez que entra a la pagina de `login` recuerda las `password` y `contraseña`.

Para ir la pagina del `login` utilizo `response.sendRedirect("login.html");`

En la pagina de `login` se verifica que la contraseña y password sean correctos:

```
if (rs.next()) {

                response.sendRedirect("index.html");

            } else {
              response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY); response.setHeader("Location", "http://localhost:8080/login");
              //in this case enter when  result size is zero  it means user is invalid
            }
```

Comment: No acabo de entender qué quieres hacer: ¿vas a usar JWT o algo similar para saber qué usuario está pidiendo datos al servidor? Se puede desactivar la sesión, pero quizá lo que quieras sea hacer que las cookies tengan una validez menor o que la sesión caduque antes...

Comment: No quiero que se almacene nada..Ya que es un login de usuario y contraseña..

Answer (score 0):

Las sesiones se almacenan en las cabeceras de las peticiones HTTP. borra todas las cabeceras menos las que te interesan para el funcionamiento de tu aplicación.

Referencia:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies